# Linked-list node eliminating function

Tags: c, struct, linked-list, singly-linked-list, function-definition

I am just trying to eliminate nodes that are containing even numbers `x % 2 == 0`.

I wrote an extremely simple function but after  I use it, the complier won't show the modified list and I don't get why.

If the head contains an even element it works properly (I did this in main), but when I try to delete something from the interior, it literally does not want to work...

I really don't know what I did wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
struct test{
    int val;
    struct test *next;
};

void erase (struct test *x)
{ 
    struct test *t;
    t=x->next;
    x->next=t->next;
    free(t);
    return ;
}

int main ()
{
    
    struct test *head,*p,*q, *aux;
    int n,i;
    
    printf("Number of elements:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    p=(struct test * )malloc(sizeof(struct test));
    
    printf("First value:");
    scanf("%d",&p->val);
    p->next=NULL;
    head=p;
    for(i=2;i<=n;i++)
    {
        q=(struct test * )malloc(sizeof(struct test));
        printf("Value %d:",i);
        scanf("%d",&q->val);
        q->next=NULL;
        p->next=q;
        p=q;
    }
    
    for(p=head;p!=NULL;p=p->next) {
        printf("%d ",p->val);
    }
    while((head->val)%2==0) {
        aux=head;
        head=head->next;
        free(aux);
    }
    
    for( p=head ; p!=NULL; p = p->next) {
        if((p->next->val)%2==0) {
            erase (p);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    for(p=head ;p!=NULL;p=p->next) {
        printf("%d ",p->val);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show what are the inputs you tried, I just copied and ran the code it seems working correctly.

Comment: yes try to put 77677 if it would work it should show you 7 7 6 7 7 and then 7 7 6 7 7 :)

Comment: I am using Code Blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the while loop

```
while((head->val)%2==0) {
    aux=head;
    head=head->next;
    free(aux);
}
```

the pointer head can be equal to `NULL`. So the next for loop can invoke undefined behavior. Moreover you are redundantly advancing the pointer p after erasing a node with an even value.

Substitute this for loop

```
for( p=head ; p!=NULL; p = p->next) {
    if((p->next->val)%2==0) {
        erase (p);
    }
}
```

for the following code

```
if ( head != NULL ) {
    for( p=head ; p->next!=NULL; ) {
       if((p->next->val)%2==0) {
           erase (p);
       }
       else {
           p = p->next;
       } 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug here:

```
for( p=head ; p!=NULL; p = p->next) {
    if((p->next->val)%2==0) {
        erase (p);
    }
}
```

What happens on the last element in the list?

`p` is not `NULL`.

`p->next` is `NULL`.

`p->next->val` will dereference a NULL pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Lets see what you function does:

```
void erase (struct test *x)
{ 
    struct test *t;
    t=x->next;
    x->next=t->next;
    free(t);
    return ;
}
```

It gets a pointer `x` to one of your structs and assumes it is not pointing to NULL.

```
x -> [         ]
```

That pointed-to struct points to another one.

```
x-> [          ] -> [         ]
```

The function creates a pointer, pointing to that.

```
x-> [          ] -> [NULL?  ]
t------------------>
```

That `t` could now point to NULL, but the function does not check it.

Then it tries to reppoint what `x` is pointing to, to whatever that unchecked thing is pointing to, which might dereferences NULL.

```
    [          ] -> [??NULL??  ] ??->?? ????[]????
t------------------>
x ----------------------------?-?-?-?-?-?-?-?-?->
```

At this point you are at risk to dereference NULL.